# 'ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer' while converting date in day/week/month/year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

While working on the date column of panda dataframe which has very large data, I am getting error:

`ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

while converting date in day/week/month/year. I have to segregate in day/week/month/format and count the corresponding ids according to that.

Below process i followed:

1. To convert column the in date format:
   `df1['REQUESTTIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REQUESTTIMESTAMP'],format= '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f')`
2. To segregate date in day/week/month/format

   `df1['Day/Week/Month/Year'] = df['REQUESTTIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x: "%d/%d/%d/%d" % (x.day, x.week, x.month, x.year))`

while executing this i am getting error:

```
`File "<pyshell#333>", line 1, in <lambda>
df1['Day/Week/Month/Year'] = df1['REQUESTTIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x: "%d/%d/%d/%d" % (x.day, x.week, x.month, x.year))
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`
```

If the error is fixed I have to group IDs according to week,month,year by using:
`df1.groupby('Day/Week/Month/Year') ['CONVERSATIONID'].agg(['count', 'nunique'])`

Expected o/p:

```
                     count  nunique
Day/Week/Month/Year                
12/41/10/2018           12       12
24/43/10/2018            2        2
30/44/10/2018            3        3

Original input file:

1050                    12-OCT-18 17.58.09.822000000<<coming correct
1055                    15-OCT-18 17.02.05.512000000<<Nat
1058                    15-OCT-18 17.10.55.264000000<<Nat
1061                    15-OCT-18 17.12.18.139000000<<Nat

Format of date column in my df coming as Nat:

    10                     1046         ...               12/40/10/2018
11                     1050         ...               12/40/10/2018
12                     1055         ...                         NaT
13                     1058         ...                         NaT
14                     1061         ...                         NaT
15                     1064         ...               24/42/10/2018
16                     1067         ...               24/42/10/2018
17                     1070         ...               30/43/10/2018
18                     1073         ...               30/43/10/2018
19                     1076         ...               30/43/10/2018
20                     1078         ...                         NaT
21                     1081         ...                         NaT
22                     1083         ...                         NaT
23                     1086         ...                         NaT
24                     1089         ...                         NaT
25                     1096         ...                         NaT
```

O/P from using strftime:

```
df1.groupby('Day/Week/Month/Year') ['CONVERSATIONID'].agg(['count', 'nunique'])
                     count  nunique
Day/Week/Month/Year                
12/40/10/2018           12       12
24/42/10/2018            2        2
30/43/10/2018            3        3
NaT                  39518    15376
```

Any help will be appreciated on how to fix the error and date coming as NaT after conversion as well?

Comment: @jezrael this is not the duplicate question as mentioned, the problem statement is different

Comment: OK, so what is expected output? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Have edited the the question with o/p required which is coming when data set is small..need suggestion to correct the error @jezrael

Comment: Sorry, so need `df1['Day/Week/Month/Year'] = df1['REQUESTTIMESTAMP'].dt.strftime('%d/%U/%m/%Y')` ?

Comment: Error is not coming using .strftime but Nat values are coming however which actually are different dates which are in correct format as well.
Have updated the o/p coming from .strftime in my question @jezrael

Comment: OK, so can you add your input data, which are incorrect parsed to NaT ?

Comment: So what need do from NaT? Remove rows? replace by something?

Comment: Just tested, cannot simulate NaT from your data, for me it working correctly.

Comment: Have updated the question with input data and location where Nat comes.....Date columns for the maximums entries after conversion is showing Nat for few working correctly. I need to have dates in correct format instead of NaT so that I can use 'aggregate' for counts. Any lead will be helpful

Comment: No idea, for me it workiong correctly.

Comment: but reopened, maybe somebody find problem...